# Make lock consider Equals() operation

Tags: c#, .net, locking

Is it possible to lock base on Equals operator being override in a class? I mean when Equals() of different objects of a class return true, lock() consider them as the same object.

Comment: Brr, massively bad idea.  The lock keyword requires a specific object, not an arbitrarily equal object.  Lock state is stored in the object header.  Luckily you can't fool it.  So no.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a solution to prevent concurrent entry into a block of code when given collection type parameters in the threads have elements in common. The first thing that comes to mind is to nest lock blocks for each collection element. But I'm no sure if it can run without performance issues. So, I'm looking to create a new class containing an collection and implement the Equals method in a way that it return true when the collections have common objects. I know this may a bad idea. But it is the only idea that I have found yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible.

The `lock` statement relays on a bit inside each allocated reference type, which is the "Sync Block" for that object in it's object header. Once a lock is taken on that object, that bit flag is set to 1. That's how runtime knows this object is currently used as a lock. There is no checking for object equality when a `lock` is taken.